# Apply gt_sparkline() to multiple numeric columns with NAs generates error

Tags: r, gt

Given a sample data as follow:

```
df <- structure(list(variable = c("cabbage", "radish", "apple", "pear", 
"monitor", "mouse", "camera", "calculator"), X2021.q1 = c(6, 
5, 6, 2.9, 2000, NA, 600, 35), X2021.q2 = c(4L, 8L, 4L, NA, 2001L, 
11L, 601L, NA), X2021.q3 = c(8, NA, 5, 4.9, 2002, 12, 602, 37
), X2021.q4 = c(8L, 3L, 2L, 7L, NA, 10L, 580L, 33L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Out:

[image]
I'm trying to plot time series for each `variable` using:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(data=list(c_across(where(is.numeric)))) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  gt_sparkline(data)
```

But it raises an error: `Error in if (med_y_rnd > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`.

How could I fix this issue? Thanks.

Reference link:

https://jthomasmock.github.io/gtExtras/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problems are caused by `NA`s.

Try `na.omit()` in pipe,

```
df %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(data=list(c_across(where(is.numeric)))) %>%
  gt() %>% 
  gt_sparkline(data)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that make sense. Or instead of dropping rows with NAs, is it possible to interpolate values for these rows or integrate ggplot which could plot lines with data containing NAs?